# Sequelize.js: Model.build returns a blank object

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize.js (4.38.0) with Typescript (3.0.3). I also have the package @types/sequelize (at version 4.27.25) installed.

I have the following code which I cannot transpile:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'

const sequelize = new Sequelize('...');
const model = sequelize.define('Model', {a: Sequelize.INTEGER, b: Sequelize.INTEGER});

var instance = model.build({a: 1, b:1});
instance.save();
```

tsc returns with the following error:

```
 Property 'save' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

So for some reason, build returns a blank object.
When I try to use create instead, the same error appears: create returns a Promise which resolves a blank object.

Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the generic type parameters explicitly, the definitions make no attempt to infer the types for the attributes or the instance type.

```
import Sequelize, { Instance } from 'sequelize'

const sequelize = new Sequelize('...');

interface Model {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}


const model = sequelize.define<Instance<Model>, Model>('Model', {a: Sequelize.INTEGER, b: Sequelize.INTEGER});

var instance = model.build({a: 1, b:'1'}); // b must be string error is now caught by typescript 
instance.save() // ok now
```